# z3: Horn clauses / Fixedpoints over inductive datatypes

Tags: z3, z3py, z3-fixedpoint

I'm trying to make assertions about program equivalence using z3's Fixedpoints, and I'm finding that any sort of recursion, even trivially decidable recursion, makes z3 totally choke. [This z3py tutorial](https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/fixpoint-examples.htm) specifically calls out program simulation as a use case for Fixedpoints, with programs being represented by recursive data types. I feel like I must be doing something wrong.

Here's a simple example:

```
from z3 import *

List = Datatype('List')
List.declare('nil')
List.declare('cons', ('car', List), ('cdr', List))
List = List.create()

nil = List.nil
cons = List.cons

a = Const('a', List)

RightLL = Function('RightLL', List, BoolSort())

fp = Fixedpoint()
fp.declare_var(a)
fp.register_relation(RightLL)

fp.fact(RightLL(nil))
fp.rule(RightLL(cons(nil, a)), RightLL(a))

BIG_ISH = cons(nil, cons(nil, cons(nil, cons(nil, cons(nil, cons(nil, cons(nil, cons(nil, cons(nil, cons(nil, nil))))))))))

fp.query(RightLL(BIG_ISH))
```

`RightLL` is a unary relation for trees that only extend to the right. `nil` only extends to the right, and if you do `cons(nil, a)` on a list `a` that only extends to the right, it continues to extend to the right. Seems like it should be trivial.

But on a modestly deep tree, the code spins indefinitely. Here's the stats after interrupting a few minutes in:

```
(:SPACER-max-depth                     7
 :SPACER-max-query-lvl                 7
 :SPACER-num-active-lemmas             9
 :SPACER-num-ctp-blocked               11
 :SPACER-num-is_invariant              27
 :SPACER-num-lemmas                    21
 :SPACER-num-pobs                      6
 :SPACER-num-propagations              4
 :SPACER-num-queries                   18
 :added-eqs                            103061776
 :bool-inductive-gen                   15
 :bool-inductive-gen-failures          12
 :conflicts                            31312
 :datatype-accessor-ax                 10890974
 :datatype-constructor-ax              25388634
 :datatype-occurs-check                51492242
 :datatype-splits                      34477418
 :decisions                            38226758
 :del-clause                           656
 :final-checks                         23408
 :iuc_solver.num_proxies               63
 :max-memory                           55.70
 :memory                               55.33
 :minimized-lits                       3476
 :mk-bool-var                          52243150
 :mk-clause                            31440
 :num-allocs                           1205059883276.00
 :num-checks                           660
 :pool_solver.checks                   330
 :pool_solver.checks.sat               263
 :pool_solver.checks.undef             1
 :propagations                         36882678
 :restarts                             198
 :rlimit-count                         277012208
 :time.iuc_solver.get_iuc              0.00
 :time.iuc_solver.get_iuc.hyp_reduce2  0.00
 :time.pool_solver.proof               0.00
 :time.pool_solver.smt.total           197.77
 :time.pool_solver.smt.total.sat       193.37
 :time.pool_solver.smt.total.undef     4.22
 :time.spacer.init_rules               0.00
 :time.spacer.mbp                      0.00
 :time.spacer.solve                    197.88
 :time.spacer.solve.propagate          10.48
 :time.spacer.solve.reach              187.39
 :time.spacer.solve.reach.children     0.00
 :time.spacer.solve.reach.gen.bool_ind 168.29)
```

I honestly have no idea what z3 might be trying here... Smaller lists, and lists that don't match the predicate (when the cons-on-the-left is near the top of the tree) complete quickly.

Am I doing it wrong? Or is z3 just incapable of handling recursively defined predicates over algebraic data types?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but potentially helpful.

I measured, how the runtime depends on the nesting depth of the query expression:

```
from z3 import *
import time

List = Datatype('List')
List.declare('nil')
List.declare('cons', ('car', List), ('cdr', List))
List = List.create()

nil = List.nil
cons = List.cons

a = Const('a', List)

RightLL = Function('RightLL', List, BoolSort())

fp = Fixedpoint()
fp.declare_var(a)
fp.register_relation(RightLL)

fp.fact(RightLL(nil))
fp.rule(RightLL(cons(nil, a)), RightLL(a))
    
expr = nil
for nesting in range(20):
    start = time.time()
    result = fp.query(RightLL(expr))
    end = time.time()
    print(nesting, " ", result, " ", round(end - start, 2), "s", flush=True)
    expr = cons(nil, expr)
```

Result:

```
0   sat   0.0 s
1   sat   0.02 s
2   sat   0.02 s
3   sat   0.03 s
4   sat   0.23 s
5   sat   2.71 s
6   sat   8.86 s
7   sat   37.21 s
```

Z3 requires an exponentially growing time to answer the `Fixedpoint` query.
For nesting depth above 7, no answer is returned as already observed in the question.

The exponential growth is not unexpected in a recursively defined tree-like problem.

Comment: Well, it's unexpected in this case, because it's trivial to check the satisfiability in linear time.